# How to use a http2 request in a MAUI Android application?

Tags: c#, maui

I have a MAUI Android application that use a gRPC service to connect with a server. It can calls to the server, but in the log of the ASP Application that hosts the gRPC service, I get an error that the http/1.1 requests are not supported.

When I configure the kestrel server, I set that is allowed http1 and http2, but anyway, http1 are not accepted. Perhaps because I am using authentication, but I am not sure about this.

In summary, I would like to know if it is needed to configure something in the Android platform to enable or force to use a http2 request.

Thanks.

Comment: There seems to be a native handler you need to set: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/issues/1923 for Android

Comment: Thanks so much, this work, it is needed to use the socket instead the http handler.

Comment: If there is a solution could one of you answer the question so this query is considered answered?